# Managing multiple app.json Configurations for Heroku Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails webapp and I want to be able to programmatically create new Heroku apps and deploy an instance of my webapp there. (I currently only have 1 instance / Heroku App. I'm trying to set it up to scale to any number of instances)

Each new heroku app needs Environment configs set, addons created, and dynos provisioned. It looks like Heroku's [app.json file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) is perfect for specifying that.

However, my app **already has an `app.json` file** that was auto-generated when I set up Heroku's Review App functionality. The existing `app.json` has a custom post-deploy script, lower tiered addons, and lower tiered dynos since I don't need the full production provisioning for my review apps.

Basically I'm finding the need to have 2 different `app.json` manifests - one for my review apps and one for my production instance.

Is there a friendly way to manage both? When creating a new heroku app can I specify the `app.json` file it uses?

Comment: I have the same need for a Node app

Comment: @user2490003 dit you ever find a solution for this?